# Abrir una función desde una imagen Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente botón que envía datos por parámetros y abre una ventana modal.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que en vez de un botón fuera una imagen con un `onClick` o una `href` pero que enviara por parametro todo igual?

```html
 <button onclick="jmgModal('miventana',{
    title: 'Ventana modal',
    width: 400,
    height: 40,
    content: 'Esta es una ventana informativa'
    },['Aceptar',function(){
    alert('Has pulsado Aceptar. La ventana se cierra automáticamente');
    });">
    Modal con botón "Aceptar"
</button>
```

Comment: No entiendo la duda ¿Has probado a hacer eso mismo en la imagen? Es decir, sustituir en ese mismo código `button`por `img`

Comment: Sii @PabloLozano y no me abre nada...

Comment: Te falla por un corchete, creo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El atributo `onclick` funciona igual en cualquier elemento visible:

```js
function showModal() {
   alert("Un modal");
}
```

```css
img { cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg" onclick="showModal()">
```

Aunque mi consejo es no usarlo o, al menos, usarlo con una llamada a una función con pocos parámetros:

```js
function clickEnImg() {
  jmgModal(
    'miventana',
    {
      title: 'Ventana modal',
      width: 400,
      height: 40,
      content: 'Esta es una ventana informativa'
    },
    ['Aceptar',function() {
        alert('Has pulsado Aceptar. La ventana se cierra automáticamente');
      }]
  );
}

document.getElementById('imagen').addEventListener('click',clickEnImg);
```

```css
img { cursor: pointer; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<img id="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg" />
```

PS: Si no te funciona, seguramente es porque te falta cerrar los corchetes (`[]`)